# How can I deploy Kooboo modules non-interactively?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, kooboo

I am currently developing a number of Kooboo modules which receive frequent updates. The modules are built automatically using a CI server.

Is there a way to deploy the modules to a running Kooboo instance after build? Since it is a large number of modules and maybe several new versions per day I would really like to avoid having to upload them manually all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that Kooboo does not provide an API to install modules. The only solution I could find was to copy the files manually (via a custom post-build event) to the Kooboo directories.

Here is what you need to do. All paths are relative to the Kooboo root directory.

- Unzip the module ZIP file in Areas/<YourAreaName>
- Copy the contents Areas/<YourAreaName>/bin to bin/

Once you have done this, the module should be deployed to Kooboo. Note that this does not run the install events and views specified in the module.